# PDO, обновить значение в столбце

Tags: pdo, php, update

Есть столбец с именем 'views', тип данных - INT.

Как можно проще обновить значение в таблице через PDO? Т.е., в нужном месте я подключаю скрипт и определенное выбранное значение в таблицы в этом столбцы увеличивается на 1.

Comment: В чем проблема то?

Comment: @andreyqin

Вариант следующий:


if ($result = $db->prepare("UPDATE `news` SET `views` = `views` +1  WHERE `post_id`=:post_id"))

не отрабатывает вообще никак.

Comment: Нужно сделать sql запрос!

    $pdo->query("UPDATE table SET value = value + 1");

Comment: @Виталий RS 

    $prepare = $db->prepare("UPDATE news SET views = views +1 WHERE post_id=:post_id");
    $prepare->bindValue(':post_id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepare->execute();

Comment: @lampa спасибо, в кавычках потерялся, поэтому и не отрабатывало.